# Why in opencl As the message size increases the bandwidth increases?

Tags: opencl, bandwidth, data-transfer

Hi in a paper about data transfer in opencl i read As the data size that we want to send to the device memory increase the bandwidth will increase, but i dont know why . can some one please explain it to me why bandwidth will increase?

Comment: There are overhead in everywhere so you need to copy pieces as large as possible. CPU power management also doesnt increase clock unless operation takes long.

Comment: The dimension of size is bytes. The dimension of bandwidth is bytes per second. The relation between both is linear.

Comment: Please can you name the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a kernel gets launched or gets transferred to/from the GPU, there is a short delay of several micro-seconds. Historically, this has been larger on AMD GPUs than Nvidia GPUs. Therefore, there's two components to the time it takes to send data: `latency + X * Y B/s` where `X` is the number of bytes and `Y` is the theoretical bandwidth. When `X` is small, `X * Y` is not much larger than `latency`. As `X` gets large, e.g. multiple megabytes, the `latency` component of the total time becomes such a tiny fraction of the total time that it becomes insignificant.